# What is the most difficult part in converting a static website to a dynamic website?

Tags: content-management-system

Consider I am having a website with 5 to 10 static information pages and there is no database. How difficult will it be to convert it to a dynamic website with userlogin and interaction, typically a cms? Do you have an easiest method to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use some open source software and stick with the out-of-the-box functionality, possibly using a readily available (free) template.

Look into Joomla, Wordpress (Blog software, but works, too), Drupal (a little more complicated), SilverStripe, ....

Answer (score 0):

Totally depends on what type of dynamic pages you want to create. If it's just plain cms like functionality it won't be a hell lot of work. Just convert the text into fields in a database.

You could think of just going for an cms and copy / paste your content into it and style the pages using css. It might be easier then building a cms that you can just get anywhere on the internet nowadays.

Joomla - CMSmadesimple etc. can be nice to look @